# What does this sentence mean? "call for a court demand to be issued for the notes"

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a news on BBC and there's a sentence I can't understand its meaning:

> **US lawmakers are calling for a court demand to be issued for the notes of the US translator** who accompanied Mr Trump to his two-hour
>   meeting with Mr Putin.

[Source](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-44870835)

Could you explain what the bold part means please?

(More specifically,

*a. US lawmakers are calling for a court / demand to be issued for the notes...* OR

*b. US lawmakers are calling for a court demand / to be issued for the notes...* ? )

Comment: https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/demand

Comment: "b. US lawmakers are calling for a court demand / to be issued for the notes..."

Answer (score 1):

definitely option b. They want the courts to issue an order allowing the lawmakers (senators and representatives) to have access to the translator's notes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_order

Comment: "Court order" is much more common than "court demand," at least in the US. I'm not sure why BBC used that terminology.

Comment: Thank you bookmanu and @Mike Harris for detailed answers. Now I totally get what it means!